# How to check if string include symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I check if a string include symbol? It looks confusing to me:

```
class Beba 
  def initialize
    while true
      puts "Qfar emri deshironi ti vnoni bebes?"
      @@emri = gets.chomp.capitalize

      if @@emri.scan(/\d+/).empty? && @@emri.scan(/\/./).empty?
        puts "Ti e emertove beben me emrin: #{@@emri}"
        break 
      else
        puts "Emri nuk mund te jete me numra/simbole, provoni perseri."
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

As you can see, at `if@@emri.scan(/\d+/).empty? && @@emri.scan(/\/./).empty?`, I don't know what to do, like which method can I use for `@@emri.scan(/\\.\).empty?` to check if my string doesn't include any symbol?

Comment: which symbols do you want to check?

Comment: ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + { } [ ] : ; ' " \ / ? > < . , @MartinZinovsky

Comment: BetWars, you need to edit the question to include that information. You might also refer to those as "special characters", as "symbols" may be confused with instances of Ruby's class [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

Comment: If `special =  "!@\#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;'\"/?><.,"`, `str.delete(special) == str` returns `true` if and only if the string `str` contains none of the characters in `special`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific characters you asked for, you can use this:

```
@@emri.scan(/[!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;'"\/\\?><.,]/).empty?
```

Will return `true` if no special character is found.

Comment: `.scan(/[...]/).empty?` is even overkill.  `@@emri =~ /[...]/`  works as well and is slightly easier to read.

Comment: @dig I agree, i prefer using `=~` or, better yet, `!~` as suggested in Cary's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
str !~ /[!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;'"\/\\?><.,]/
```

returns `true` if and only if the string `str` contains none of the characters in the regex's character class (else `false` is returned).

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you are looking for special characters.
Use something like

```
"Hel@lo".index( /[^[:alnum:]]/ )
```

It will return nil if no special charatcters.

[:alnum:] includes all 0-9, a-z, A-Z.

**IF YOU WANT TO GO FOR SPECIFIC CHARATCERS**

place all characters in a string & create regex like

```
characters = "!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;'\"\/?><.,"
regex = /[#{characters.gsub(/./){|char| "\\#{char}"}}]/
```

& than use this regex to see if any of them exist in  string like

```
if some_string =~ regex
```

Comment: Faisal Lqbal but it;s leting me to name baby, i don't know why.

Comment: Didn't get your point, but seems @Gerry below told exactly what you asked for

Comment: But the problem is at slash, becuase slash will stop ".  @Muhammad Faisal Lqbal

Comment: You have assumed that all characters other than letters and digits are "special characters". Why? The OP's comment (posted before you answered) shows only a relatively small number of "special characters". Not included, are the hyphen, backslash, tilde, vertical bar (`"|"`), backtick, backslash and others.

Comment: Seen that comment after answering, my bad.
Tried to edit answer accordingly to some extent after reading that.